# Do we ever see Morn speak?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the entirety of the DS9 series (or in his appearances in the other shows), do we ever see Morn speak?  Do we hear him speak?

The difference between the two: seeing someone speak could be where we see someone but it's too noisy to hear them.  Only if we actually hear something is it *hearing* them speak.

Comment: You know Morn, he never shuts up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time Morn ever actually speaks during any scene that made it into the final cut (according to Mark Allen Shepherd, the actor who played Morn) [was in the background of a scene being shot](https://www.startrek.com/article/mark-allen-shepherd-was-born-to-be-morn-part-1)

> The circumstances surrounding my first day on the show were so unusual. When they shot the bar scene in Quark’s where Morn is telling the funniest joke in the universe, they told me I could go ahead and tell my joke. And when Sisko gets off of the turbolift and just as he walks towards Quark’s, if you listen carefully to the background sound you might actually hear Morn saying “Finalism finger fink. Obligatory quotient yokefellow, coconut kachina cosmological argument. Bank swallow fish story, inculpate minuteman. Stress certifier in lecithin. Hard-hearted dill, divine minded domineer, mind reader sextuplet, garden fly honey suckle garbage. Palter rimfire, green peace. Change is the ultimate solution. Twenty-fourth century humor. You may not get it right away.”

> In the book The Making of Star Trek: Deep Space Nine, the first chapter of the book is “The Funniest Joke in the Universe” and it is about exactly that and how I came to be on the show. That was the only time I got to say anything while the cameras were rolling, but it´s not the only time that they considered Morn for a speaking part. There have been numerous scripts where they originally had Morn speaking. One such script had to do with the alternate universe. Unfortunately, they always got written out.

Comment: I've watched that scene a bunch of times and you don't actually see him speak.

Comment: Yeah, not directly. The audio is apparently in the background. His point is it's the only time he speaks as Morn during a final cut

Comment: I've listened to it too. You don't hear or see him speak. You see some people laughing at a joke he made, but his lines happen off-screen and are unaudible.

Answer (score 6):

Once, we *see* Morn speak but don't hear him speak.

- In the episode *You Are Cordially Invited*, during the bachelorette party, we can see his lips moving (probably singing along), but the music is too loud to make out any words.
- When he's talking to the tribble at the end of *Trials and Tribble-ations* (pointed out by Valorum in the comments)

Comment: Sorry, but you see his mouth opening and closing *in time to him moving up and down as he dances*. He doesn't appear to be singing or talking.

Comment: @Valorum That's disputable...

Comment: Not really. His mouth is doing the same thing about a minute earlier in the scene when he's watching the fire swinger dude.

Comment: A better example (and less disputable) would be when he's talking to his tribble at the end of '*Trials and Tribble-ations'*

Comment: @Valorum Are you intending to post a separate answer about that?  If not, I'll edit it into mine.

Comment: Not really. There are several occasions when you see his mouth move, including the pilot episode, *'The Jem'Hadar'*, etc etc

Comment: According to [_Memory Alpha_](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Morn), in the German version of the episode _The Jem'Hadar_, he does speak; he is just about to tell Quark what has been troubling him when Quark simply walks away. Resigned, Morn mutters, "Dann nicht…"

Comment: @SteveV Are you going to post that as an answer or should I?

Comment: you can go ahead and add it to yours!

Answer (score 6):

As [SteveV pointed out in the comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250164/do-we-ever-see-morn-speak/250165?noredirect=1#comment684358_250165), according to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Morn):

> Morn never spoke a single word throughout all of Deep Space Nine, with the only time he was ever depicted vocalizing being his laugh in the episode "The Nagus". In [the German version of the episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/de/wiki/Der_Plan_des_Dominion) "[The Jem'Hadar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Jem%27Hadar_(episode))", however, he does speak; he is just about to tell Quark what has been troubling him when Quark simply walks away. Resigned, Morn mutters, "Dann nicht…" (roughly meaning "So much for that…"). These words are not uttered in the original English version.

Comment: I think in the English version he says "Er...." I may be mistaken