# When did Morn not speaking on-screen become a running joke?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Morn had remained silent during the duration of the series (the English series, that is).  At some point, it became a running joke ("You know Morn, he never shuts up"), but when was the first time it was teased like this?  I know that [he did speak in the German version of season 2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/250169/141465) (meaning it couldn't have been a running joke then), and I recall in the season 6 episode, *Who Morns for Morn*, they teased this, although I think it was teased before this.  Was this the first time?

Comment: In the first season he couldn't speak because his makeup wouldn't allow it. I'm assuming it stems from that.

Comment: [See also](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJ4rnue9cSw)